# Mouseclicked Complication

Tags: java, swing, click, mouse

As you can see here I correctly defined my variables but when I try runing a method lol once the user has clicked the Jlabel label it will not permit me to enter Graphics g in the parameters of lol method? Why is this HELP!

```
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(hut);
    label.setIcon(icon);
    label.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter()
{
@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){

    **lol(Graphics g);**
}

private void lol(Graphics g) {
    System.out.print('\u000C');
    storelook = new ImageIcon("/Users/alexspallone/Desktop/Programing/Pictures For Java/scroll.jpg").getImage();
    g.drawImage(storelook,0,0,null);
}
});
```

Comment: Can you describe you intentions?  What is it your are trying to achieve, yes I understand you want to do something when the image clicked, but what and how?

Answer (score 1):

Your code does not compile.  `Graphics g` is saying, "Define a variable named g that is a Graphics object".  You can't pass that in to `lol` on the same line.  Here's how to make your code *compile*:

```
    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent m) {
        Graphics g = null;
        lol(g);
    }

    private void lol(Graphics g) {
        //...
    }
```

But it won't do what you expect.  You can't get a usable `Graphics` there.  The only way I know how to get a Graphics object is in one of the `paint/paintComponent` methods that you override in `JComponent`.  You probably can't do what you intend to do here.  If you let us know what you're trying to do, we can help you though.

Comment: I am trying to call the method lol once the user has clicked the Jlabel label.

Comment: @user2451511 Call that method from within the `paintComponent` method, but only if someone has clicked first.  Have `mouseClicked` set a boolean variable and `paintComponent` only run `lol` if the variable is true.

Comment: I am trying to display a picture (that is the Jlabel label) and once the user clicks on it run lol();.

Comment: How can I tell if someone has clicked it if mouseClicked is a boolean variable?

Comment: HELP GUYS I AM HAVING SOOOO MUCH TROUBLE!

Comment: @user2451511: regarding `"HELP GUYS I AM HAVING SOOOO MUCH TROUBLE! "` -- please don't shout. Please edit your original question if you're still having problems and show your updated question and code. Please don't beg. Also, mouseClicked is not a boolean variable but rather a method. Also, and again, what happens when you try to use ImageIcons?

Answer (score 1):

You need to read a tutorial on how to call methods since your method call does not have the type name in it:

Not:

```
myMethod(int foo);
```

but rather:

```
myMethod(foo);
```

You only have the type in the parameter list when *creating* the method:

```
public void myMethod(int foo) {
   // .....
}
```

To solve your problem, I suggest that you instead use ImageIcons to hold your Images and then in your mousePressed method, call `setIcon(myIcon)` on a JLabel that will display your image.

Answer (score 0):

your code still won't do because you do not have a usable Graphics Object.
I suggest you change your code to something like that:

```
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){

    lol=true;
    label.repaint();

}

    public class Label extends JLabel {
        storelook = new ImageIcon("/Users/alexspallone/Desktop/Programing/Pictures For Java/scroll.jpg").getImage();
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            if(lol)
            {

            g.drawImage(storelook,0,0,null);
            }
        }
    }
```

edit: still this is not a very good solution, since there is actually a method to draw icons into panels. This is shown in the answer of ***Hovercraft Full Of Eels***

Comment: I disagree with your recommendations. 1) Why override a JLabel's paintComponent when you can just inject an ImageIcon with ease. This is what JLabels were built to do, and you're recommending to go around this. And 2) you should *never* read in files within a `paintComponent(...)` method, not unless you want your program to have very slow graphics and slow user responsiveness.

Comment: Yea you are right. I did it in a short time without thinking a lot but  my primary goal was to show a way how to make it work. It is certanly a bad one as you pointed out.

Comment: about the `paintComponent(..) ` as you say it would make the program really slow as the pictures would be read in everytime the method is called...
sorry for writing such a bad code..